# How to throw show_404 if file not exist in Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I'm using Codeigniter 4 for my application.
If the view php page file is missing in Codeigniter 3, I use these codes to throw a 404 error.

```
public function family($type)
{
    $page = 'family';
    if (!file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages/family/'.$page.'.php')) show_404();
    $data = array(
        'title'   => 'Families',
        'content' => 'family/'.$page
    );
    return view('index', $data);
}
```

Using Codeigniter 4 I'm trying to use the same, but it doesn't redirect to 404.
[image]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function family($page)
{
    $filepath = WRITEPATH . 'uploads/' . $page;

    if (!file_exists($filepath)) {
        return $this->controller->throwPageNotFoundException();
    }

    $data = array(
        'title'   => 'Families',
        'content' => 'family/'.$page
    );
    return view('index', $data);
}
```